# How to ssh into a docker container running on a different network?

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, networking

I have a docker container running on a local host with private ip 172.17.0.3.
I want this to be publicly accesible over the internet so that anyone in the world can ssh into this docker container. Is this possible and if possible how? I am trying to create a small public cloud filled with instances of docker containers in my local network which people from all over the world can access and I am sitting behind a NAT which might cause issues.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: On which stage do you get your Global IP. Is it just your router NATing or maybe your ISP is also using NAT? In first case you could use port forwarding, and in second there is not much you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Forward port from inside container to the host please, for example

```
docker run -it --name mydocker -p 8080:80 docker/tensorflow:latest
```

Comment: I dont want to access it from host. I want to access it from another network..rather anyone in the world should be able to ssh into it..not just me

Comment: Firstly, you need a VPS to host your OS
then you must forward port from inside docker container to host 
After that, you can access from any where